# how to update status using mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update status in MySQL. Here is my table design and data.

[image]

Here I want to update `status='y'` where `id='9'` as well as update `status='n'` where `status='y'` on one query fire.

Comment: Why do you want "one query fire" ? You can, but it's not getting any more legible

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

Comment: I might use two queries in a single transaction

Comment: This is a two query operation.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the `UPDATE` statement you are looking for:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET status = CASE 
                WHEN id='9' THEN 'y' 
                WHEN status = 'y' THEN 'n'
                ELSE status
             END
```